# Default value for select box preselected on page open

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have an array of colors.

I want to make a select box from that array so that by default first item from that array is preselected.

Here's the code that I try to use, but it fails:

```
<select ng-model="test" ng-init="colors[0]" ng-options="color for color in colors"></select>
```

This anyway gives me blank selection box by default, values will apear only when I select something.

Here's the plunker demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y0O61u49HBY9Evp7XrxI?p=preview

**EDIT:** in my actual code I have a lot of selectionboxes that are created from ng-repeat directive. Solution (from @Diryboy) with manually setting *scope.test* outside *select* tag is not preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Looks changing the line 23 to the following works

```
$scope.test = $scope.colors[0];
```

Comment: yeah, this will work. The only problem that I have a lot of selectionboxes created via *ng-repeat*, and would like a solution based upon adding something inside *select* tag, rather than setting ng-model value outside that tag.

Comment: I'm afraid that you have to ng-repeat the option tags then.